# Why is Spotify using my webcam (AppleCamera)

Tags: malware, macos

I'm running Mac OS Mojave. I've just run the following command into terminal to see which applications are using my web cam.

```
lsof | grep "AppleCamera"
```

Google and Spotify showed up:

```
Spotify 668 salmon  txt REG 1,4 345968 16727731 /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera

Google 39415 salmon txt REG 1,4 345968 16727731 /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera
```

I assume Google Chrome has access to my camera for sites that may require it. But I have no idea why Spotify would need access? Is this something to be worried about?

Comment: Check and see if you can set a profile picture in the application. It could be there to take a selfie as an option. Lsof doesn't mean the app is actively (or ever has used) your camera, it's simply registering it's interest in potentially using it.

Comment: This company has been noticed negatively in the past with regard to data protection. https://www.zerohedge.com/news/2015-08-21/youve-been-warned-spotify-wants-spy-you-every-way-imaginable

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same thing.
It turned to be the audio driver that enabled some shady/unuseful thing to track your face for audio spatialization. Try to disable this or restore previous driver's version.

Answer (score 2):

Spotify uses "[Spotify Codes](https://www.spotifycodes.com/index.html)", which is based on QR codes. It would need camera access for that.

Answer (score -3):

If you're sitting on a parked airplane, no movement, spotify will ask you if you're in a car. Only way it would know I'm in some sort of a transportation vessel would be if it's accessing my camera and recognizing the confined space.

Comment: Using the camera "to recognise the confined space" is pure speculation, and a poor one. It makes no sense. If it wanted to sense its surroundings, using the microphone would be a much, much better way to do that (echos). Do you have any way to support your speculation?

Comment: I should imagine Spotify uses GPS to track your speed over distance to determine if you're in a car. Writing a program to reliably detect if you were in a vessel would be unreliable and insanely difficult.